# Ignite on server

Tags: ignite

I have a server,and have a container on server, on which started `Ignite` node(s).
And know that server configs (IP,container port etc.).
And want to connect(find) to this node from my PC(from `Intellij Idea`).
Namely  I want to start another `Ignite` to which must connect to node on server.
How do my new starting node configuration?

With `TcpDiscoverySpi` or `CommunicationSpi` and how with IP and port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start a node on your PC with a configuration where IP finder, that is set for `TcpDiscoverySpi` will contain list of IPs and ports of your remote cluster.

Most likely it will be more than enough to configure [static IP finder](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.6/docs/cluster-config#static-ip-based-discovery) on your side.

Simply you can create the static IP finder the way below and set this discovery bean into configuration of all the nodes (servers and clients)

```
        <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>server_1_ip:47500..47509</value>
                            <value>server_2_ip:47500..47509</value>
                            <value>server_3_ip:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: Ok.Please show me one example  of ignite configuration on server and local,which should find node on server. And please tell me when use 
TcpDiscoverySpi  and when CommunicationSpi .

Comment: Update the answer above adding an exemplary configuration of static IP finder that has to be added to every node's configuration. Don't forget to replace 'server_N_ip' with actual addresses. Port range should be modified as well if you change discovery port numbers on your side.

TcpDiscoverySPI is usually created manually to set an IP finder and change a port number where the node should bind to. TcpCommunicationSPI instance is on the user side if you need to modify low level parameters like port, timeouts, etc.

Comment: Both TcpDiscoverySPI and TcpCommunicationSPI  have setLocalPort.
Please say me difference?

Comment: @daniels, TcpDiscoverySpi is used by nodes in order to build and maintain a cluster of them. The messages that are sent over this SPI are system/internal and they are sent from one node to other (neighbor on the left). So it means that the cluster is organized as a ring and TcpDiscoverySpi is used to exchange internal information between the nodes. On the other hand when a node needs to send a message directly to the other (cache put/get, compute, event, etc.) it uses TcpCommunicationSpi opening a direct connection to the remote node.